# not such file or directory is found

Tags: directory

I have downloaded a bin installation file named "LianjaAppBuilder-1.2.2-linux-x86_64-installer1.bin". I want to run it in terminal but when i type "./LianjaAppBuilder-1.2.2-linux-x86_64-installer1.bin" it says not such file or directory is found. How can I run this file?

Answer (score -1):

1. Check you are in same directory where it downloaded. If not, go to the directory where it downloaded using the `cd` command.
2. Give execute permission to the file using the command: `chmod u+x file`
3. Now try to execute `./example-file`
   If asked for root permission, prefix the command with `sudo`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH REALLY "CD" COMMAND WORKED , I APPRECIATE YOUR HELP AND PRAY FOR YOU !!!